# User Testing of Website

Tags: javascript, testing, video-capture

I am searching for a web service which can record the actions done by my clients on my website. There is a service known as "[Userfly](http://www.userfly.com)", but this service is a paid service. They offer the service for free 10 recordings per month only. If you guys know something similar to this but for "FREE" please share and also i would like get suggestions on recording the clients action done on websites.

Thanks A Lot...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280516/alternatives-to-userfly-com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Google Analytics](http://analytics.google.com). It has a system that allows you to learn what portions were accessed more than others, graphs and everything. It does not recreate what users did in animation, but it gives you the entire flow and everything and it's got the best price Free!

I've used it for quite some time now and it does give me very interesting information.

Comment: Agreed. Analytics allows you to gain deep insight into how users traverse your website if you're willing to wire things up correctly (granted, that can be something of a pain if you're doing pageloads with ajax, but it's still very possible).

Comment: Thanks a lot Cyril & Paul for the suggestions.Google Analytics is indeed a great app, but if you guy find something similar to userfly and clixpy except that it should be free it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Clixpy](http://clixpy.com/).
Clixpy is a tool very much like Userfly, allowing you to do essentially the same thing: record user sessions on your website such as keystrokes, page scrolls and navigation to multiple pages.
The big difference between the two is that Clixpy is much cheaper than Userfly, as you can get 100 captures for $5. 
Such services generates lot of server load i think you will not get it for free.

Comment: Thanks a lot Djko for let me knowing Clixpy. Your point is valid that such services generates a lot of load. If you ever find such services that are free please let me know. And one thing is What are the technology(programming lang) used for this type of services... JavaScript?

Comment: Of cause javascript. You just capturing all movements and clicks on document. And also capturing HTML maybe and all cookies.

Comment: And what about animations & video by capturing screenshots ?

Comment: I do not think they capture video or image. They do not need it. You can just get HTML and CSS + JS and generate whole page as user sees it. Than you get all the mouse movements and clicks. And that is all you need to recreate all the user do on a page. Even generate video out of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Djko. I hope you will help me with any problems on JS.